# PHP Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php

I get the following error in PHP 7.4

> ```
>  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in
> ```

When running this function

```
function check_admin($user)
{ 
     $is_admin = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("Select * from Accounts where [Name] = '".$user."'"));
         array();
         if($is_admin['name'] != false){
            if($is_admin['ip'] != ip($user)){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return array($is_admin['name'],$is_admin['gm_level'],$is_admin['ip']);  
                }  
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }   
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `mssql_fetch_array()` can return false if there are no matching rows.

Comment: what is this `ip($user)`?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the number of returned rows are greater than zero.

```
function check_admin($user)
{ 
     $is_admin = mssql_fetch_array(mssql_query("Select * from Accounts where [Name] = '".$user."'"));

     //checks if the number of rows returned are greater than zero.
     if(mssql_num_rows($is_admin) > 0){ 
         if($is_admin['name'] != false){
             if($is_admin['ip'] != ip($user)){
                 return false;
             }
             else{
                 return array($is_admin['name'], $is_admin['gm_level'], $is_admin['ip']);  
             }  
         }
         else{
             return false;
         }
     }else{
         return false;
     }
}
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: This `if(mssql_num_rows($is_admin) > 0)` condition will check if the number of rows is greater than zero or not. Rest of the code are yours.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading PHP Fusion from 9.0 to 9.03.50 resolved the issue.

Comment: This doesn't qualify to be an answer. You have to be more specific about what difference really affected the code.